# The QWebFrame, QWebPage, and QWebview is not found in the QT 4.8.5?

Tags: qt

I have a QT 4.8.5 in linux 64-bit machine, and the QT creator 3.0.0, it is not able to find the QWebFrame, QWebPage, and QWebView? Here is my pro file.

*

```
*[code]
QT += webkitwidgets
QT += widgets
TARGET = QT_Webkitwidgets
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
[/code]*
```

*
Here is the main file.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>


class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE qint32 MultOfNumbers(int a, int b) {
        qDebug() << a * b;
        return (a*b);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", new MyJavaScriptOperations);
    view->load(QUrl("./shreyas.html"));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Same problem - after updating the pro file. I have re-run the qmake, but the problem is same.

```
TARGET = QT_Webkit
TEMPLATE = app

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
    QT += webkitwidgets
} else {
    QT += webkit
}


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module naming changed between Qt4 and Qt5. To be compatible with Qt5 and Qt4, do the following in your .pro file to include the correct modules:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
    QT += webkitwidgets
} else {
    QT += webkit
}
```

Comment: Well, I am getting the same problem. I have updated the question now with your pro file suggestion. I have re-run the qmake. But the problem is persisting.

Comment: Are you sure you have the qt webkit development packages installed? e.g., libqtwebkit-dev on Debian based systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you recompile the Qt lib. Maybe you don't include the QWebKit lib.

[Qt configure](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html)

./configure -webkit ...

For be sure if you have the QWebkit lib. You can search the all *.so depend of Qt in your system lib.

Answer (score 0):

All those classes are in `webkit` module in Qt 4, and also Qt 4 doesn't have widgets and webkitwidgets module, those are modules in Qt 5, so in the .pro file you should add `QT += webkit` and remove `QT += webkitwidgets` and `QT += widgets`, or add those only if Qt5 is used.

Comment: It is still not able to include the file - main.cpp:4:21: fatal error: QWebFrame: No such file or directory
 #include <QWebFrame>

Comment: Have you _run qmake_ after you modified the project file?